# How to test usage of a comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

How can it be tested that a comparison is used to get a result?

```
x = 42
y = 43
is_identical = id(x) == id(y)
```

and to ensure that it is not written something like this to trick the test:

```
is_identical = False
```

**Update**:

The background is that students need to upload their homework into a tool that automatically runs unit tests (or pytests) to show them how good the uploaded code is. In one exercise, they should just perform a comparison and not be able to trick the unit test by writing True/False directly as variable assignment. Functions are not used yet.

Comment: This is in fact quite a common first step in TDD! Nedt, make sure there's a test for objects which should be identical, and another for objects which should not be.

Comment: This requires more context: could you share the function that you want to test?

Comment: Why would someone want to "trick the test"? I don't understand your objective here. In any case, there's no way to know if a boolean value originally came from a comparison if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well, one obvious way is to test both cases when the values are equal and when they're not. That should be done anyways, and whether any function is used or not is a detail of implementation. Unless the function is passed from the outside, then you mock it.

Comment: @bereal Okay, I guess I'll have to give it more context here: The test is for Python beginners who have to give a homework task by showing that they can program a comparison. That's why no function is required, because they haven't learned it yet. However, their submissions should be checked automatically (there are many submissions), so such a test makes sense.

Comment: @interjay -- yes, that is what I'm asking, see also my comment above. Hope, that everything make more sense now.

Comment: I guess you'll have to build a proper parser, which may be trivial, e.g. `import dis; dis.dis('is_identical = id(x) == id(y)')` includes `COMPARE_OP` in the output

Comment: Updated question, hope it's better now. @Chris_Rands That looks promising at first glance. :)

Comment: @interjay "Trick" doesn't have to be taken literally. It's also a somewhat-glib description of *unintentionally* writing code to a specific test or tests, rather than writing code to the *specification* that the tests are supposed to verify.

Comment: When students upload their code into a verifying tool, it should run it through multiple test cases for better coverage. That's how all online judges I know work. You can even generate random test cases and compare the output with your own code.

Comment: Is it really necessary to do this though? If you wrote say 1000 tests with random numbers generated (you could obtain the expected results with your own solution) then there is no way a user could easily 'trick' all the tests without automating their solution as intended?

Comment: Yes, it is a good alternative to achieve this particular goal. But to be honest, I would also like to know how to do that. I'm currently looking at this `dis` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am satisfied with the [answer from amanb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907609/2648551). Nevertheless, in the meantime I have also found a solution that gave me good results. Instead of the library [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) I used [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

```
def testcase_ok():
    import ast
    to_proof = "is_identical = id(x) == id(y)"  # will pass
    assert any(isinstance(node, ast.Eq) for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(to_proof)))


def testcase_fail():
    import ast
    to_proof = "is_identical = False"  # will fail
    assert any(isinstance(node, ast.Eq) for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(to_proof)))
```

In addition, this is one way to get the relevant part of the source code without hardcoding `is_identical = …` (without check if variable is given, for the sake of clarity):

```
import inspect
import file_to_test as submission

codelines = inspect.getsourcelines(submission)[0]
to_proof = [line.strip() for line in codelines if line.strip().lower().startswith("is_identical")][-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This hacky monkey patchery seemed to work out:

```py
# test_foo.py

from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from importlib import reload

class FooTest(TestCase):

    def test_comparison_used(self):
        import foo
        self.assertFalse(foo.is_identical)
        with patch("foo.id") as id_:
            reload(foo)
            id_().__eq__.assert_called()
```

When `foo.py` uses the "cheat" method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

x = 42
y = 43
is_identical = False # id(x) == id(y)
```

I get `E           AssertionError: Expected '__eq__' to have been called.`

but if I do `is_identical = id(x) == id(y)` then the test passes.

Comment: This works for Python >= 3.6. And yes, this is indeed a solution that worked for using `__eq__`, which seems to be the case for `==`, but unfortunately not for `is`. So `is_identical = x is y` is not recognized here. Probably there is a simple addition to this. In any case, this hacky solution is already very helpful!

Comment: @colidyre You can use [`imp.load_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) for Python 2. `is` shouldn't be used for numeric comparison anyway - start an interactive shell, enter `>>> n = 257` and then `>>> n is 257`. `is` will return the correct answer only for a very small range of numbers pooled in CPython impl (signed shorts IIRC) and this behaviour can vary between different implementations of Python.

Comment: @hoefling I didn't mean Python2, just Python3 lower than 3.6. But that's good to know ;). And also `is` was meant to compare id(x) and id(y) and not x and y. Sorry, that was wrong, corrected it (in the question).

Comment: @colidyre again, comparing ids via `is` is wrong. Run `python -c "x = object(); print(id(x) is id(x))"`, what do you get?

Comment: Argh, sorry... That was again not very clear. I meant comparing ids via `id(x) == id(y)` or `x is y`. Nevertheless, I just deleted it now, that wasn't my focus, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution makes use of constants in code objects to identify bool values True/False and the bytecode instruction `'COMPARE_OP'` to identify comparison operation. The code can be improved to add more cases, but this is just to give you a head start. To show all conditions, I've set all the args in the function as optional:

```
In [130]: def catch_trick_bool(unit_test_result=None, student_compare=None,student_trick=None):
     ...:     student = str(input("Enter student name: "))
     ...:     # import dis - Use this to further examine code objects.
     ...:     # Eg. use  dis.dis(co_unit_test) to view the code objects for 
     ...:     # the unit test expresssion
     ...:     if unit_test_result:
     ...:         co_unit_test = compile(unit_test_result, 'none', 'single')
     ...:         if False in co_unit_test.co_consts:
     ...:             print("Bool value 'False' returned from Unit Test")
     ...:     elif student_compare:
     ...:         co_student_compare = compile(student_compare, 'none', 'single')
     ...:         if '6b' in co_student_compare.co_code.hex():
     ...:             print("Student {} performed the comparison successfully".format(student))
     ...:     else:
     ...:         co_student_trick = compile(student_trick, 'none', 'single')
     ...:         if False in co_student_trick.co_consts:
     ...:             print("Student {} tried to set a bool value of 'False' for the test".format(student))
     ...:

In [131]: catch_trick_bool(unit_test_result='is_identical_unit_test = False')
Enter student name: John
Bool value 'False' returned from Unit Test

In [132]: catch_trick_bool(student_trick='is_identical_student_trick = False')
Enter student name: John
Student John tried to set a bool value of 'False' for the test

In [133]: catch_trick_bool(student_compare='id(x) == id(y)')
Enter student name: John
Student John performed the comparison successfully
```

**Explanation**:

The following shows how the hex bytecode `0x6b` is searched for in the hex representation of the bytecode instruction for the code object. This bytecode corresponds to the opname `'COMPARE_OP'`. This instruction indicates a comparison operation in the code.

```
In [137]: co = compile('is_identical = id(x) == id(y)', 'none', 'single')

In [138]: type(co)
Out[138]: code

In [139]: dis.dis(co)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (y)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (is_identical)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

In [140]: co.co_code
Out[140]: b'e\x00e\x01\x83\x01e\x00e\x02\x83\x01k\x02Z\x03d\x00S\x00'

In [141]: co.co_code.hex()
Out[141]: '6500650183016500650283016b025a0364005300'

In [142]: dis.opname[0x6b]
Out[142]: 'COMPARE_OP'

In [143]: '6b' in co.co_code.hex()
Out[143]: True

In [144]: co2 = compile('is_identical = 5 > 2', 'none', 'single')

In [145]: co2.co_code.hex()
Out[145]: '640064016b045a0064025300'

In [146]: '6b' in co2.co_code.hex()
Out[146]: True
```

Similarly, bool values are resolved to `LOAD_CONST` bytecode instructions which can be easily accessed with `co_consts`:

```
In [147]: co3 = compile('is_identical = False', 'none', 'single')

In [148]: dis.dis(co3)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (False)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (is_identical)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In [149]: co3.co_consts
Out[149]: (False, None)

In [150]: False in co3.co_consts
Out[150]: True
```

**Conclusion**:

The dis-assembled code objects can help identify the source of a bool value. If it is explicitly defined as in the above case, the bool value will be resolved as a constant `LOAD_CONST` bytecode instruction. If it is deduced implicitly through a boolean expression that uses comparison(such as 5 > 2), the code will be resolved to a specific bytecode instruction `COMPARE_OP` to indicate comparison operation. You can expand the code further to check for truthy values too and modify as per your requirement.

Comment: I've tested it and it worked! Thank you. :) I'm just not sure if I should accept this answer as a solution or mine (which would be a bit odd, maybe).

Comment: You are closer to the actual problem than me. Select the answer that works best for you.